# Read lines from file in order, parallelization based on file structure

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-mining

I have a text file formatted as such:

```
itemID_1:
(observation 1 for itemID_1)
(observation 2 for itemID_1)
...
(observation k_1 for itemID_1)
itemID_2:
(observation 1 for itemID_2)
(observation 2 for itemID_2)
...
(observation k_1 for itemID_2)
...
```

I want to create a dataframe where each row is (itemID, observation) (there can be multiple rows for the same itemID).

I would go about doing this in python like so:

```
rows = []
file = open('my-file.txt')
cur_itemID = None
for line in file:
    if re.match(r'\d*:', line):
        cur_itemID = re.search(r'(\d*):', line)[1]
    else:
        rows.append([cur_itemID, line])
```

So I need to read the file in order, but only so that the correct itemID is associated with the rows below. It would be possible to parallelize this if we could process the rows for each item simultaneously (i.e. starting at row "itemID_i" until "itemID_{i+1}"). I'm not sure how to do something like this in Spark and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Is the number of observations per item constant? If so, you can add row number to each row and then divide it by this number to find a corresponding itemID. If not, you can still do it by using row numbers, and then search for the itemID with the biggest number not exceeding current line number. I am not sure it's more efficient than just reading rows in order

Comment: How large is the text file (how many items, how many observations each)?  And is it possible to see the sample data in more representative data so that I can see the data types.  For example, instead of "(observation 1 for itemID_1)", is it "100" or "string text lines"?

Comment: @Emma the file is large (too large to fit in memory) and there are an arbitrary number of observations per item. All observations are the same format: a tuple (datetime, int, int). Yaroslav, is splitting the file by itemID and then parallelizing that way considered good practice, or are there existing methods that are preferable?